# Textbox not displaying answer from a formula

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add the selected values from different dropdownlists. is there a problem with my code? because nothing shows up when i click the button to add them. heres the code

```
 protected void btnSum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int a = Int32.Parse(ddlEval1.SelectedValue);
    int b = Int32.Parse(ddlEval2.SelectedValue);
    int c = Int32.Parse(ddlEval3.SelectedValue);
    int d = Int32.Parse(ddlEval4.SelectedValue);
    int f = Int32.Parse(ddlEval5.SelectedValue);
    txtScore.Text = Convert.ToString(a + b + c + d + f);
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your method and investigate the values of `ddlEval1.SelectedValue` and `txtScore.Text`.

Comment: Have you registered an exception handler with the AppDomain or similar? One that should handle all unhandled exceptions?

Comment: Replace ddlEval1.SelectedValue with ddlEval1.SelectedItem (and others as well, ddlEval2.SelectedValue, etc.).

Comment: Would be more helpful if you could share at least a code snippet of one of your dropdownlists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work, but please consider some error handling. When the selected item does not contain an integer representation, you will get an exception.

```
protected void btnSum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int a = Int32.Parse(ddlEval1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    int b = Int32.Parse(ddlEval2.SelectedItem.ToString());
    int c = Int32.Parse(ddlEval3.SelectedItem.ToString());
    int d = Int32.Parse(ddlEval4.SelectedItem.ToString());
    int f = Int32.Parse(ddlEval5.SelectedItem.ToString());
    txtScore.Text = Convert.ToString(a + b + c + d + f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
int sum = a + b + c + d + f;   //or double depending on your values.

txtScore.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);
```

Comment: Question is, do you want you to add up the values together to a sum or so you want to just simply concatenate them for diplay?